How to store JWT token in next-auth session
I'm using firebase auth provider (email/password) option with next-auth v4 in my next.js project. What I want to do is access the JWT token from the session on my client using the useSession() hook. this is my authorize function:
CredentialsProvider({
    name: 'Credentials',
    credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith@example.com" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password", placeholder: "*******" }
    },

    async authorize(credentials, req) {
        console.log("attempting to authorize creds");
        try {
            const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                auth,
                credentials?.email as string,
                credentials?.password as string,
            );
            console.log(userCredential.user.uid);
            const token = await userCredential.user.getIdToken();
            console.log(token);

            const user: MyUser = {
                id: userCredential.user.uid,
                email: userCredential.user.email,
                token: token

            };
            const sendUser = { id: userCredential.user.uid, ...userCredential.user, token: token }
            return sendUser;

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Invalid credentials.")
            return null;
        }
    }
})

But upon doing this, I am only getting the email field and not the id and token. I verified this by adding the token in the email field and indeed I was getting the token in the email field but there was no token or id field. I should've gotten something like
{
    "id" : 1234,
    "email:"test@gmail.com",
    "token": "ASDasdasFMASFasf123ad"
}

however, I only get this:
{
    "email:"test@gmail.com"  
}

